# Why can we use the scattering matrix formula for decay rate?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

The derivation of the scattering matrix $S_{\alpha\beta}$ requires the states to exist asymptoitcaly, why can we use it for a decay rate where clearly the decaying particles does not exist asymptotically

Answer (score 3):

The *decaying* particle exists asymptotically *in the past*. The *decay products* exist asymptotically *in the future*. The decay itself is then just a momentary self-interaction, and so it's just the right jam for scattering theory.

Comment: I still do not get your argument. The decaying particle can not exist for t goes to - infinity since it has a finite life time. Also the decay products do not necessarily need to be stable particles, they may decay again and thus also do not exist asymptotically